# What is the difference between locking an element version and locking a Label Type [lbtype]

Tags: clearcase

"`cleartool lock`" command can be applied to lbtype object "`REL1`" as well as "`file element foo.c version \main\3`".
Assume `REL1` has been applied to `foo.c@@\main\3`.
Assume `foo.c@@\main\2` is unlocked.

Applying lock to lbtype object "`REL1`" will prevent applying "`REL1`" to any more versions of any other files.
This will not prevent replacing "`REL1`" on an `foo.c` version `\main\3` with another yet unlocked LABEL TYPE "`REL2`" for example.
This will prevent relocating "`REL1`" to `foo.c@@\main\2` assuming `foo.c@@\main\2` is unlocked.

Applying lock to "`foo.c@@\main\3`" will prevent removing the already applied RELEASE LABEL type to that particular version to be replaced or to add any more new LABEL TYPE to that `foo.c@@\main\3` of the element or removing any already applied Release Label Types to `foo.c@@\main\3`.

Applying lock to an element version doesn't prevent checkout for the element version.

Are all the above statements correct, so that I understand difference locking Release Label Types and File Element Versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cleartool lock`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm)

> > Applying lock to lbtype object "REL1" will prevent applying "REL1" to any more versions of any other files.

yes:

> Label type. If a label type is locked, you cannot do the following:
>
> - Use the type in an rmtype, rename, or mklbtype –replace command
> - Attach or remove a version label of that type with mklabel or rmlabel (This includes moving a label from one version to another with mklabel –replace.)
>
> > This will not prevent replacing "REL1" on an foo.c version \main\3 with another yet unlocked LABEL TYPE "REL2" for example.

Not exactly "replacing": you can add many different labels on a given version.

> > This will prevent relocating "`REL1`" to `foo.c@@\main\2` assuming `foo.c@@\main\2` is unlocked.

Yes:

> Version Lock:
>
> If a version is locked, you cannot do the following:
>
> - Attach a label using mklabel
> - Remove a label using rmlabel or mklabel -replace
> - Attach an attribute using mkattr
> - Remove an attribute using rmattr or mkattr -replace
> - Remove the version using rmver