# How to avoid the error "Please freeze your view config-specs before invoking make."?

Tags: clearcase

I am getting the following error while compiling on ClearCase:

```
ERROR: Please freeze your view config-specs before invoking make.
```

I have created one branch and set config specs but I am still getting that error.

How would you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The terme "freeze" generally refers (in this context) to a config spec which is *not* based on "`LATEST`".

`LATEST` is a shifting label which means it can move (while the make is in progress)

It is best to create a dedicate view which selects in its config spec a label

```
element * a_label
```

Each time you want to build:

- set a new label ([`cleartool mklabel`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm) as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711514/6309) or in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25913734/6309)) on your sources
- [lock the lbtype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599031/6309),
- and modify the config spec of that view accordingly.

The view will be considered "frozen" (in that it does refer to frozen fixed versions), and make will be able to proceed in confidence.